# Can't hide loading popup after DB loads. Using Cordova and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

For some reason I can't hide the "loading" popup once a database has been populated. It shows fine on start, but will not hide in the .done function. There is probably something simple I am missing.

Here is the code:

```
$.mobile.loading('show', {
    text: 'Populating Items Database.  This may take several minutes',
    textVisible: true,
    theme: 'b'
});

var count = 0;

$.getJSON(remoteJsonURI, function(json) {
  //console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
  $.each(json, function(index, element)
   {
    count = count + 1;
    db.transaction(
    function (transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql('SQL GOES HERE', 
                [],
                sqlWin, 
                sqlFail
            );
            transaction.executeSql('SQL GOES HERE',
                [],
                sqlWin,
                sqlFail
            );
            }, txFail, txWin
        );


    })
    .done( function() {
        $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
        alert("Items Database Loaded");
        $.mobile.changePage( "#search", { transition: "flip"});

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using default loading popup of cordova 
This will start the popup loading.
`navigator.notification.activityStart("Please Wait", "Its loading your homepage.....");`

Below code will stop the loading popup :
`navigator.notification.activityStop();`

I have changed your code:

```
navigator.notification.activityStart("Please Wait", "Populating Items Database.  This may take several minutes");


var count = 0;

$.getJSON(remoteJsonURI, function(json) {
  //console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
  $.each(json, function(index, element)
   {
    count = count + 1;
    db.transaction(
    function (transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql('SQL GOES HERE', 
                [],
                sqlWin, 
                sqlFail
            );
            transaction.executeSql('SQL GOES HERE',
                [],
                sqlWin,
                sqlFail
            );
            }, txFail, txWin
        );


    })
    .done( function() {
        navigator.notification.activityStop();
        alert("Items Database Loaded");
        $.mobile.changePage( "#search", { transition: "flip"});

    });

});
```

You can also manually close the popup by using javascript.
`setTimeout(function(){navigator.notification.activityStop()}, 5000);`  this will close the popup after 5 seconds

Comment: Nothing shows up after adding this. Is this in base cordova or do I need a plugin?

Comment: Navigator.notification is of cordova so you dont need any other use plugin yea i hope u have downloaded notification plugin $ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.vibration using cli.